# Find and replace from a different text document from each new line

Tags: ffmpeg, cmd.exe, notepad++, find-and-replace, batch-rename

I have some file conversion software that which works through cmd and doing something along the lines of:

```
converter.exe input.wav -o output.wav --ffmpeg "-af volume=0.1"
```

I'm trying to process a bunch of files through it but I can't figure out how to do it with the software itself so what I've tried doing is

```
dir /b > files.txt
```

to spit out the list of all the files like

```
file1.wav
file2.wav
file3.wav
```

then I'd use every new line on this text document to dictate what the "input.wav" would be. I would also need to do the same thing with the "output.wav" but not replace the original so like add a "_1" on the end or something. I'd then make a batch file that does something like this

```
 converter.exe file1.wav -o file1_1.wav --ffmpeg "-af volume=0.1"
 converter.exe file2.wav -o file2_1.wav --ffmpeg "-af volume=0.1"
 converter.exe file3.wav -o file3_1.wav --ffmpeg "-af volume=0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Open files.txt with Notepad++

- Press Ctrl+H
- Find what: `(^.+)\.wav$`
- Replace with: `converter.exe $1.wav -o $1_1.wav --ffmpeg "-af volume=0.1"`
- Search mode: Regular Expression
- Click on Replace All. Save your file.

**Before**
[image: Input file]

**After**
[image: Output file]